# Showing lot of image in scrollview causes lag

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiscrollview, uiimageview, lag

here's the problem.
i want to make a photo viewer app that shows 6 image for every page, and it using scrollview page control.

but now i have a problem, because adding to many subview cause lag. and i don't know how to handle that.

here's my code:

```
HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
HUD.labelText = @"Loading...";
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDAnimationFade;
[self.view addSubview:HUD];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

const CGFloat itemWidth    = 160.0f; //panjang
const CGFloat itemHeight   = 127.0f;
const CGFloat buttonWidth  = 157.0f; //panjang button
const CGFloat buttonHeight = 125.0f; //tinggi button
const CGFloat marginHorz   = (itemWidth - buttonWidth)/3.0f;
const CGFloat marginVert   = (itemHeight - buttonHeight)/2.0f;

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:storyUrl];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

    jsons = JSON;
    NSString *urll;

    int index = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    //start
    for(id item in jsons){

        //[self.button removeFromSuperview];

        if ([item objectForKey:@"img_medium"] == [NSNull null]) {

            urll=[item objectForKey:@"img_medium"];

        }else{

            urll=[item objectForKey:@"img2_medium"];

        }


        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        UIImageView *imgggg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonWidth , buttonHeight)] ;
        [imgggg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urll] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_photo.png"]];


        [button addSubview:imgggg];
        button.tag = index;

        //button placing
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*itemWidth + marginHorz, row*itemHeight + marginVert, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(switchView:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NSLog(@"offset but %f",column*itemWidth + marginHorz);
        NSLog(@"column %d",column);
        NSLog(@"row %d",row);
        //UIImage *pic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];

        UILabel *labeling = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 157, 45)];
        [labeling setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.45]];
        [labeling setText:[item objectForKey:@"title"]];
        [labeling setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

        labeling.numberOfLines = 0;
        [labeling setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [labeling setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]];

        //UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:pic];
        //[img setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
        [button addSubview:labeling];
        [scrollView addSubview:button];

        index++;
        row++;

        if (row == 3) {
            row = 0;
            column++;
        }

        NSLog(@"index %d",index);

    }
    //end

    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
    [self listSubviewsOfView:scrollView];

    //end block ui
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;

    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Request Time Out" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [errorAlert show];
    //end block ui

    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

}];
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago i have also face the same issue and i have used [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView). It has very awesome feature that if your App is running below iOS6 then it will user PSTCollectionView and if your app running above iOS6 then it will user UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to implement view recycling. Since you are implementing a scrollView, a UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, which implements a lot of cells. It manages the memory by reusing the cells.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/TableViewCell.html) is the documentation you might want to read.

Answer (score 0):

Switch all of your scrollView's child view's CALayer's interpolation methods for magnification and minification from their default `linear` to `nearestNeighbor`, this will allow for very quick upscaling and downscaling, in your zoom completion block set it back to whatever they were before (I suggest trilinear for smoothest looking UI / gfx)

Amazed this isn't a default thing for UIScrollView considering Apple does this very method in all of their apps for speed optimization.